# Gulp task to merge Javascript and Frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, gulp-inject

I am completely new to WebDev and Gulp. I am currently creating an own project for experimenting. I want to use Angular 1 and Bootstrap. What I have done so far is to install Bootstrap via NPM. Create an main.less file, where I import the Bootstrap.less file and all my own less files. This main.less file will then be compiled into one public CSS-File, which gets injected into the index.html with gulp-inject.

Now to the Javascript-Part. I also want to have one Javascript-File which gets injected into the index.html.

First of all is this advised, or should I just automatically inject all of the Javascript-Files which I will create?

And how do I address my Frameworks? I know I can do `require('angular')` for example in a Javascript-File. But where do I put this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot things that you are trying to learn all at once.  I would suggest getting one part down before moving on to the next part. This is especially true if you are just starting to learn Web Development.

I would advise to learn and then nail down your build environment first as it will provide you with valuable tools that will save you a lot of time.

If you haven't installed gulp yet you will need to install it via npm like the following:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

**Note:** You may have to use sudo npm install gulp --save-dev if you recieve errors installing npm packages depending on your operating system and its environment.

The --save-dev part will place a reference to your development dependencies inside your package.json file.  This will allow anyone who is setting up your project on their system to npm install and they should get all of the dependencies needed to run your project installed on your system.

Below is a list of things you will want to install via the npm install package-name --save-dev method I described earlier.

```
npm install gulp --save-dev  (needed for to run gulp commands)

npm install gulp-less --save-dev (compiles your less files in to css)

npm install gulp-concat --save-dev (concats your js files into one file)

npm install gulp-uglifiy --save-dev (compresses, minifies your js file)

npm install gulp browser-sync --save-dev (loads your project using a http server and enables hot reloading of the page.)
```

**UPDATE:** As an alternative to installing the above packages one by one you can use the following package.json file.  Just place it in your projects root and type npm install in your command line(you may have to use sudo npm install depending on your system.

**package.json**

```
"name": "bootstrap-angular-less",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Basic Angular 1 build package with support for bootstrap and less.",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Larry J Lane",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

After you have installed all of the dependencies, make a file name gulpfile.js and place in the root of your project.  After the file is created add the following code inside it.

```
**gulpfile.js**


//require all of the gulp modules
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var util = require('gulp-util');
var path = require('path');




var dirs = {
  src: './app/src',
  dest: './app/build'
};

var jsPaths = {

jsSrc: dirs.src + "/assets/js/*.js",
jsDest: dirs.dest + "/assets/js/"

};

var lessPaths = {
  src: dirs.src + "/assets/less/main.less",
  dest: dirs.dest + "/assets/styles/"
};

var templatePaths = {

  src: dirs.src + "/*.html",
  dest: dirs.dest + "/"

}



// Browsersync server that watches CSS, HTML, and JS
gulp.task('server', ['html','css','js'],function() {


    browserSync.init({

      server: {
      baseDir: dirs.dest,
      serveStaticOptions: {
          extensions: ['html']
      }
     }
    });


    gulp.watch(dirs.src + "/assets/less/**/*.less", ['css']);

    gulp.watch(dirs.src + "/assets/js/*.js", ['js']);

    gulp.watch(templatePaths.src, ['html']);

    browserSync.watch(templatePaths.dest + '*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);

});

// CSS Preprocessing. Uses Less to pre-process and pipes stream to Browsersync.
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src(lessPaths.src)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(lessPaths.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//HTML processing.
gulp.task('html', function() {

    return gulp.src(templatePaths.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(templatePaths.dest));
});


gulp.task('js', function() {

  return gulp.src([jsPaths.jsSrc])
    .pipe(concat('bundler.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsPaths.jsDest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

//Default task that will run when type gulp in the command line.
gulp.task('default', ['server']);
```

Next you will need to create a few folders within the root of your project. Create a folder named app and place two new folders within it. The first one should be named build and the second one src.  You will be doing all of your development out of the src folder. After you have created those folders place a file named index.html in the src folder with the following contents.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A basic gulp browser sync build template</title>
<link href="/assets/styles/main.css" type="text/css" rel ="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


This is a basic gulp browser sync build template with support for less.

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bundler.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once all that is put together, from the command line type gulp and it should load the project inside your browser.  Any changes made to the index.html, less files inside app/src/assets/styles/less/, javascript files inside of app/src/assets/js will be update automatically and display in the browser.  All less files inside the less folder will be compiled into one file named main.css and all js files inside the js  folder will be compiled into one javascript file named bundler.js.

Any less files you want to load like less files from bootstrap for example you can load inside the main.less file via an import. Example below from the main.less file.

**main.less**

```
//import less files
@import 'partials/_globals.less';
```

All files that your own css you will need to place in the partials folder inside the less folder. I attempted to make the structure as easy possible so take a look around and let me know if you have questions.

That is it for now take it for a test drive to see how it works and if you think it will work for you then we can work on adding the Angular integration...

Comment: What's is the problem

Comment: Well still need to figure out, what is the most elegant way to add the third party frameworks. Bootstrap was no problem, but I don't know how to handle Angular

Comment: When I get time I will implement that